# http://127.0.0.1 got redirected to http://10.114.5.20/

Tags: networking, proxy

I have IIS installed in my local machine. When I have my IE settings to use a corporate proxy pac script, when I browse http://127.0.0.1 instead of going into my IIS it goes to http://10.114.5.20/. If I set my IE settings to a manual proxy (with the bypass proxy by local adress checked) the http://127.0.0.1 show my IIS application.

Any ideas what is wrong with the original settings? How 127.0.0.1 gets redirected to another IP? Where to look?

My computer is w7 64 bits laptop.

Don't know who is 10.114.5.20. It is not my local ip. It is not any of my dns servers. It is not my default gateway.

Pac script could return two proxies: or 10.114.5.11 or 10.114.5.14. Not sure what the 10.114.5.20 machine could be, maybe it is the default gateway of the proxies...

Just a last update:

I download and saved the PAC script locally, and changed the http://... URI to a local file://C:/... one. And surprisingly enough, it worked. I mean the http://localhost now goes to my computer, not to the strange http://10.114.5.20/.

Reading the PAC script file I notice that when opened with Notepad all text goes into one line, but opening with Wordpad I see several lines. Opening in binary, the carriage return is a unix style one (0A) instead of the windows one (0D0A).

So I supose the explanation comes down to say the Automatic configuration script setting in IE doesn't understand unix style carriage returns When parsing the pac script, so it always returned the proxy, never DIRECT.

Comment: Knowing what is at 10.114.5.20 might help you. Is it your machine? Another proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the corporate proxy pac script.  It does not allow the "bypass proxy for local addresses".

Try `ping -a 10.114.5.20` or `tracert 10.114.5.20` to try to figure out who is at that address.

FYI... if you want to use the default settings for the proxy, then don't use "localhost", instead, use your real IP address.  The Proxy server should redirect the request back to your own machine.

Comment: But why 127.0.0.1 traffic goes to the proxy? I don't see any case in which this could be helpful in any way...
"bypass proxy for local addresses" what exactly means? "localhost", "127.0.0.1", [my local ip], [ip's in my network range], [private ip's]? All of the above, some of them?

Comment: It means ALL local IPs, including but not limited to, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0 and localhost.  If you have multiple NICs, those IPs too.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, but what it means "ALL local IPs" exactly? All Ip's registered in all NICs of my machine plus the "built in" 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Basically, any IP you want to get to is going through that proxy including the ones your machine uses locally like 127.0.0.1 (loopback) and the IP registered to your NIC.  So... yes.

Comment: Looking at pac script now, the "bypass proxy for local addresses" is in fact manually coded in the pac script itself, right? Strange enough part of the script checks  isInNet(host,"127.0.0.0","255.255.255.0")  and returns DIRECT if it is true.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Use automatic configuration script" in the LAN Settings in IE?  My guess is that the pac script is not configuring IE properly and local requests are still going out to the proxy server.  IE needs to stop the request, not the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like corporate IT has an entry in your hosts file that's redirecting you.

Open Windows Explorer and browse to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`. Open the `hosts` file with Notepad or another text editor. Do you see an entry that directs http://127.0.0.1 somewhere else?

If so, commenting that out should fix the issue.

Comment: That may be true, but would be very odd. There would be no value in redirecting localhost connections.

Comment: I've heard of stranger things. I could see a corporate IT guy deciding that locally hosted sites are a security risk. MS introduced IIS Express because of IT department restrictions on developer computers. Worth checking out, anyway.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with host file. There is no localhost entry in my host file, but in any case i'm not browsing to http://localhost, I'm going directly to http://127.0.0.1

Comment: Browsing to localhost or going directly to 127.0.0.1 are *exactly* the same thing. If they weren't all proxies could be bypassed by simply inputting the IP address instead of the domain name.

Comment: I think localhost first goes to DNS for resolution (or host file is DNS doesn't resolve)...